# bootstrap accordion in color

Tags: css, colors, accordion

I know this sound crazy or easy but I'm not getting any result. 
I'm working on bootstrap accordion and I'm trying to figure out how to write in CSS to allow show ALL color Blue in (icon, text and background color) in at the SAME TIME using CSS :focus when person clicked the link or accordion...

please see one line of accordion of codes...

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Members</a>
```

or please see the whole sample of each accordion buttons...

```
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <dl class="accordion">
    <dt><span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Manage</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-chevron-up"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
    <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item "><i class="fa fa-tachometer blue" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboard</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posts</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
    </dd>

     <dt><span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-chevron-up"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
    <div class="list-group">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posts</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;comments</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Privacy</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Notifications</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Emails</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sites Infor</a>
</div>
    </dd>
```

Comment: So you want multiple elements to change color to blue when you click on something else?

Comment: yes, multiple elements to change color to blue when click.

Comment: You will not be able to achieve this with just the `:focus` pseudo-class. If you are open to using JS/jQuery along with CSS, the answer is easy and I can walk you through that.

Comment: oh ok thanks, i guess i have to write in jquery.